# How to get subtotals on particular category in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to understand DAX. I want to get subtotals for category Cat1 in a Matrix visual. This is my table

```
Cat1        Cat2       Sales
Fruits      Apples      30
Fruits      Apples      50
Fruits      Apples     100
Fruits      Cherries    50
Fruits      Cherries    80
Vegetables  Tomatoes    20
Vegetables  Tomatoes    30
Vegetables  Tomatoes    10
```

After creating measure below,

```
 Sales running total in Cat1 = 
 CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table1'[Sales]),
    FILTER(
    ALLSELECTED('Table1'[Cat1]),
    ISONORAFTER('Table1'[Cat1], MAX('Table1'[Cat1]), DESC)
```

I would expect subtotals to appear for Cat1 only, but they appear also for Cat2. And the result in Matrix does not change if I change Cat1 to Cat2. What is then the purpose of having Cat1 or Cat2 in the DAX formula?

Example of expected result:

```
Cat1        Cat2       Sales
Fruits      Apples      30
Fruits      Apples      50
Fruits      Apples     100
Fruits      Cherries    50
Fruits      Cherries    80
Total:                 310
Vegetables  Tomatoes    20
Vegetables  Tomatoes    30
Vegetables  Tomatoes    10
Total:                  60
```

And this is what I get:

```
 Cat1       Cat2       Sales
 Fruits     Apples      30
 Fruits     Apples      50
 Fruits     Apples     100
 Total:                180
 Fruits     Cherries    50
 Fruits     Cherries    80
 Total:                110
 Total:                310
 Vegetables Tomatoes    20
 Vegetables Tomatoes    30
 Vegetables Tomatoes    10
 Total:                 60
 Total:                 60
 Total:                370
```

Comment: What's your expected results? And it seems to me that you're mixing up concepts of subtotals and running totals. Can you explain more?

Comment: How can I make a table in comments like I did in the question itself? I want to show an example how I expect the table should be looking. Tried backticks, but with no luck.

Comment: You can just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44228281/edit) your own post to add an example.

Comment: Please see the corrected post with expected result.